# Jupyter Notebooks predicting always the same class with GPU and pretrained Keras checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

When I predict on a pre-trained VGG16 based checkpoint with `load_weights` I am always getting the same class and output tensor. This only happens when I use my GPU (I have 2 GPUs).

If, on the other hand, I only use my CPU by setting:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

I get the expected results.
This happens for me in Jupyter Notebooks, but it does not happen in google colab. In google colab I get accurate results no matter what.

- I am using Keras 2.4.3
- Tensorfow 2.4.1
- CUDA 11.2

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share standalone code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!